# Vue - define event handlers in array of dynamic components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want do create some some different components by looping through an array of components like in my example. But I want to create different event handlers for each component. How can I define them in my componentData Array and bind them while looping?

```js
componentData: [
   { name: TestPane, props: { data: "hello" }, id: 1 },
   { name: TestPane, props: { data: "bye" }, id: 2 },
],
]
```

```
<div v-for="component in componentData" :key="component.id">
   <component v-bind:is="component.name" v-bind="component.props">
   </component>
</div>
```

Comment: where are the handlers (methods) defined?

Comment: In the method section. I want to do something like:
{ name: TestPane, props: { data: "hello" }, id: 1 , @click: doSomething()},

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `v-on` directive. Let's understand how Vue bind your event listeners to the component first:

When you add a `@input` to a componnet what you are actualy doing is `v-on:input`. Did you notice the `v-on` over there? This means that you are actually passing an 'object of listeners' to the component.

Why not pass all of them in one go?

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div v-for="component in componentData" :key="component.id">
      <component v-bind:is="component.name" v-bind="component.props" v-on="component.on">
    </component>
</div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    componentData: [
      { name: TestPane, props: { data: "hello" }, id: 1, on: { input: (e) => { console.log(e) } } },
      { name: TestPane, props: { data: "bye" }, id: 2, on: { input: (e) => { console.log(e); } } },
    ],
  })
}
</script>
```

As you could guess you can listen to the events now inside of `on` object. You can add more if you would like as well:

```
{ 
  name: TestPane,
  props: { data: "hello" },
  id: 1,
  on: { 
    input: (e) => { console.log(e) },
    hover: (e) => { console.log('This component was hovered') }
  } 
}
```

Comment: @Kevin worth to say that the answer of `Boussadjra Brahim` can be applied as well since with this method you can't listen to native events. Only events emitted by your child component

Comment: I added an example of using custom events emitted from children

Comment: both solution work for me as for now, thanks to both of you.
I have one more small question.. normale I can write props as :data=this.message.
Now I do it with props: { data: this.message }.
But now this.message is always undefined although I defined it in the data section

Comment: You are probably accessing it in the data arent you? Something like `data: () => ({  data: { 
message: this.message }, message: 'Hello'  })`. This will fail since `this.message` doesn't know what the `message` is already. You can solve this by using a computed property

Answer (score 2):

Add method names to your array like :

```
componentData: [
   { name: TestPane, props: { data: "hello" }, id: 1, method:"method1" },
   { name: TestPane, props: { data: "bye" }, id: 2 ,method:"method2"},
],
```

in template :

```
  <component ... @click.native="this[component.method]()">
```

or add another method called handler which runs the appropriate component method :

```
 <component ... @click.native="handler(component.method)">
```

```
methods:{
  handler(methodName){
   this[methodName]();
 }
...
}
```

if the events are  emitted from components, you should add their names and bind them dynamically :

```
componentData: [
   { name: TestPane, props: { data: "hello" }, id: 1,event:'refresh', method:"method1" },
   { name: TestPane, props: { data: "bye" }, id: 2 ,event:'input',method:"method2"},
],
```

```
<component ... @[component.event]="handler(component.method)">
```

Comment: Worth to say that dynamic event name was only introduced in ... I'm trying to find the version but can't

Comment: i'm also fetching the vue 2 releases to see that